# Inserir uma informação em duas collections no MongoDB com Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tenho duas collections: cursos e participantes.
um participante ao se inscrever em um curso, quando dou um GET em um curso qualquer, precisa retornar os participantes inscritos(**participantes**) e quando dar um GET em um participante qualquer, precisa retornar os cursos inscritos (**cursosInscritos**).

Quando dou um POST ou PUT no participante e/ou curso, a informação não salva nos campos 'participantes' ou 'cursosInscritos', ele retorna com status 200 **mas não salva no banco de dados**

Como posso fazer?

**cursosSchema:**

```
const cursoSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

    nomeCurso: {type: String, required : true },
    participantes: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'participanteSchema', required : false}]
})
```

**participantesSchema**

```
const participanteSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    nomeCompleto: { type: String, required : true},
    cursosInscritos: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'cursoSchema'}]
})
```

**controller**

```
exports.inscricaoCurso = (req, res) => {
    const {nomeCurso, local, periodo} = req.body
    const inscreverCurso = new Cursos({
        nomeCurso, local, periodo, participantes: req.params.participanteId,
    })
    inscreverCurso.save()
    try {
       Participantes.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.participanteId}, {$push: {cursosInscritos: inscreverCurso._id}})
       res.status(200).send({ mensagem: "Inserido com sucesso" })

   } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({ mensagem: Error })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce nao deveria estar usando o `async/await` na sua funcao `inscricaoCurso`? No seu model de `Participantes`, ele depende do `id` do model `inscreverCurso` que ainda nao estar salvo por ser uma operacao assincrona. Logo voce deveria esperar salvar o `inscreverCurso` para ai sim quando for executar o `Participantes.finOneAndUpdate` (depreciado) ele tera o valor de `inscreverCurso._id`.

```
exports.inscricaoCurso = async (req, res) => {
  const { nomeCurso } = req.body;
  const inscreverCurso = new Cursos({
    nomeCurso,
    participantes: req.params.participanteId
  });
  try {
   await inscreverCurso.save();
   await Participantes.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.participanteId },
    { $push: { cursosInscritos: inscreverCurso._id } }
   );
   res.status(200).json({ mensagem: "Inserido com sucesso" });
  } catch (error) {
   return res.status(500).json({ mensagem: Error });
  }
 });
```

Recomendo voce reescrever o update do `Participantes` desta forma:

```
 try {
  await inscreverCurso.save();
  let participante = await Participantes.findById(req.params.participanteId);
  participante.cursosInscritos.push(inscreverCurso._id);
  await participante.save();
  res.status(200).json({ mensagem: "Inserido com sucesso" });
 } catch (error) {
  return res.status(500).json({ mensagem: Error });
 }
```

Tente fazer desta forma e faca os testes. 
Mais uma cois, na parte de inscreverCurso, voce nao deveria verificar se o nome do curso ja existe e ai somente atualizar a lista de participantes?